# Delegate returns right color, but still wrong

Tags: c#, colors, bitmap

I have a delegate

```
private delegate Color ColorDel(int x, int y);
```

which returns a color at a point, to be used with `Bitmap.GetPixel(x,y)`

Even though i put the color into the bitmap directly before, as a `Color.Red`,
the return color is the same to all the ARGB but not on the name, which is `ffff0000` instead of Red as the `Color.Red` actually is.
`ToKnownColor` doesnt do the trick either.

Any input on the matter?

Edit, code:

```
class ColorDelegateTest
    {
        private delegate Color ColorDel(int x, int y);

        private static bool FoundColor(int x, int y, Color color, ColorDel dlgt)
        {
            var theColor = dlgt.Invoke(x, y);
            //theColor = "{Name=ffff0000, ARGB=(255, 255, 0, 0)}"
            //Color.Red = "{Name=Red, ARGB=(255, 255, 0, 0)}"
            var r = dlgt.Invoke(x, y) == color; //False
            var t = dlgt.Invoke(x, y) == Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0); //True
            var f = dlgt.Invoke(x, y) == Color.Red; //False
            if (r || t || f)
                return true;
            return false;
        }
        private static void ItterateColors()
        {
            int xMax = 300;
            int yMax = 300;
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(xMax, yMax);

            ColorDel colorDelegate = new ColorDel(bmp.GetPixel);

            for (int x = 0; x < xMax; x++)
                for (int y = 0; y < yMax; y++)
                {
                    bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Red);
                    FoundColor(x, y, Color.Red, colorDelegate);
                }
        }
    }
```

Erik

Comment: If you could post the actual code (not just the delegate declaration) that would make it much easier to help you.

Comment: By the way, this has got **nothing** to do with using a delegate. Which you could easily have tested yourself by trying to use `GetPixel` directly.

Comment: Yeah true, i should have checked the underlying functions first and see if it behaved or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Color.Red` includes a bit indicating that it is a known color, while `Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0)` does't so they don't compare as equal. One way to do the comparison is to just compare with `.ToArgb()`:

```
dlgt.Invoke(x, y).ToArgb() == Color.Red.ToArgb()
```

Comment: Thanks, didnt even think of that!

Answer (score 1):

try using Color.FromName("Red") instead of Color.Red

P.S. Would have helped a lot to answer if more detailed question was there